# Android M Auto Backup with multiple devices

Tags: google-backup

https://developer.android.com/preview/backup/index.html

How does the new Android M Auto Backup feature work when you have multiple devices using the same Google Account (e.g. phone and tablet)? Does it keep separate per-device backups if you have the same app installed on multiple devices? If so, when the app is installed on a new device, how does it know which backup to restore?

The link above doesn't address this at all.

Comment: I can't speak to how it stores the backup data, but as for knowing which to restore, it should follow the same system as Lollipop: when you setup a new device, it actively shows you a list of your previous devices, and when they were last used, so you can choose which one to restore from, and even lets you deselect the apps you don't wish to restore.